# Can you split a .gitignore file into multiple files?

Tags: git

For example, a `.gitignore.d` directory of fragments instead of just one big `.gitignore` file.

*NB: I am not talking about `.gitignore` files in subdirectories.*

Comment: Would the $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, ~/.gitignore, and the core.excludesfile fit your need? Probably not, as its hierarchical like per-directory .gitignore files, but it's worth bringing up.

Comment: I've never seen an ignore file that was so big I felt the need to split it up.  The most I've used is perhaps 10 or 15 lines, but more typically, just a few lines.

Comment: I simply would like to have each ignore rule in its own file. Since this seems impossible (at least as of Git 1.8.0), I ended up implementing a custom merge driver called git-merge-line-sets(1) to instead treat the .gitignore file as essentially a set of lines, which solved my underlying problem of having unnecessary merge conflicts re: .gitigore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be useful to me, too.  And I've contemplated (lazy) ways to achieve a similar effect.

(There appears to be a mistaken assumption that .d/ structures are only useful at a certain *physical size* only - but it's purely to do with reducing complexity when multiple external systems want to manage a single resource without painful overhead.  Consider [/etc/apt/sources.list](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=5&query=sources.list&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en) - most people's sources.list files are less than 5 lines, but everyone understands the benefits of having the partner sources.list.d/ structure available.)

Returning to **.gitignore** -- [etckeeper](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) resolves this problem for itself within **/etc/.gitignore** using the age-old classic of:

```
 # begin section managed by etckeeper (do not edit this section by hand)
  ...
 # end section managed by etckeeper
```

This section can change on any etckeeper package upgrade, natch.

So one obvious option is to utilise a similar sub-system to this, identifying it appropriately.  A bit messier, code-wise, perhaps than the git-merge-line-sets, but *arguably* a better documented / more conventional / nicer workflow approach.

Answer (score 1):

No, you probable can't. But you could generate it, perhaps in your Makefile.